# Vim: highlight current block/paragraph?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to make Vim highlight the current block/paragraph? Example:

> No hightlighted no hightlighted no hightlighted no hightlighted no hightlighted no
> hightlighted no hightlighted no hightlighted
>
> **Hightlighted hightlighted hightlighted hightlighted hightlighted
> hightlighted hightlighted hightlighted hightlighted hightlighted**
>
> No hightlighted no hightlighted no hightlighted no hightlighted no hightlighted no
> hightlighted no hightlighted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the same caveats as @Mattrition's answer (`:set wrap`), you'll get a permanent and dynamic highlighting (of the entire current line) with

```
:set cursorline
```

If it's not just a single wrapped line, but an actual paragraph consisting of multiple physical lines, you'd have to build such yourself. There were plugins that emulated the *cursorline* before it became a built-in setting; you could take inspiration from there (i.e. reuse the autocmds to update). However, because matching across multiple lines is costly, I don't think the performance of that would be satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `:set wrap`, so that you are only visually wrapping your lines, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> will be sufficient to highlight the paragraph.

However, if you have new lines within your paragraph it will only select text up to the new line. An alternative is to use `vip` to select everything excluding the next empty line, or `vap` to include the next empty line.